# Gazebo easiest way to apply preload force on a model programmatically?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am implementing a feature that exports robot models to Gazebo. One of the the features that you the CAD software I am using has is the ability to designate spring joints that will have a force applied to them as soon as the simulation starts. I have found several ways to apply forces including via ROS, URDF, and plugins. However, ROS would require running a separate program or script and using plugins would require me to effectively have the program generate and compile cc++ code, which would not be an easy feat. As such, I am wondering what would be the best way to apply a force on the joint at the start of the simulation?

Is there a way I can parametrize plugins from gazebo? For instance, compile a generic plugin file and then have commandline arguments to specify which joints receive how much force? Or would I have to go and using scripting and other features to both write and compile plugins for any model that uses this feature?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9037/gazebo-easiest-way-to-apply-preload-force-on-a-model-programmatically?/) by [Skylion](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1252/skylion/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Using Spring Reference and Stiffness solved my issue in this regard. Unfortunately, I have not found any features in Gazebo to run commands at specified times.

See [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9079/how-to-schedule-forces-at-specific-times/) question if that is what you are looking for

---

Originally posted by [Skylion](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1252/skylion/) with karma: 5 on 2015-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [imlearning](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2903/imlearning/) on 2016-11-17**:
@Skylion - Did the applied forces work to move links? Were you able to get the joint/ spring in "compression"? Please let me know if you have any thoughts in regards to: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14826/how-to-reduce-joint-distance-after-simulation-start/ and http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14837/how-to-move-a-prismatic-or-other-joint-to-negative-limits/. Applying forces (possibly without a joint even) may be an option?